# xetex: different glyphs between default languages (polyglossia and babel)

Tags: xetex, symbols, languages

I write a thesis in German, but have to cite lots of Greek polytonic text. 
The strange thing is that when I set the default language to German and the other language to Greek, I get different glyphs for the lambda and theta:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=poly]{greek}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

λαμβδα

\end{document}
```

If I change default and other language and vice versa I get different glyphs (wouldn't be a problem if the glyphs with German default language wouldn't look that ugly). 
[image: German]

[image: Greek]

any help apreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[Script=Greek]`. Note that `Mapping=tex-text` is automatically applied, so you don't need the `\defaultfontfeatures` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a feature of CMU Serif, that uses different glyphs for Greek when the script is Latin.

You can do

```
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[Script=Greek]
```

and the result will be the same. However, it's better to properly segregate the other language using `\foreignlanguage` or the `otherlanguage` or `otherlanguage*` environment.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=poly]{greek}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

Deutsch \foreignlanguage{greek}{λαμβδα} äöü

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the line

```
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Mapping=tex-text}
```

is not needed, because the feature is automatically applied.